# Как лучше всего настроить работу GraphQL в GraphQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, graphql

Есть три приложения. Все они на Rails актуальной версии. Представим их в такой цепочке для лучшего понимания:

```
App 1 -> App 2 -> App 3
```

Описание каждого приложения:

- **App 1**. Отправляет запросы к **App 2**. Не имеет свою БД.
- **App 2**. Принимает запросы от **App 1**. Отправляет запросы к **App 3**. Имеет собственную БД.
- **App 3**. Принимает запросы от **App 2**. Имеет собственную БД.

**App 2** является центральным звеном, которое при запросе от **App 1** должно также одновременно сделать запрос к **App 3**, подготовить что-то и вернуть **App 1**.

Сейчас я попробовал прописать запрос к **App 3** внутри схемы **App 2**.

Но выглядит это очень странно (не сам запрос или его наличие, а то, как с этим работать). И меня не покидает чувство, что я делаю все не так. Я не понимаю как я буду что-то "готовить" и отдавать в **App 1**, ведь нужно работать еще с локальной БД у **App 2**.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше всего реализовать эту идею?

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от того как вы хотите организовать взаимодействие между **App 1** и **App 2**.

1. **Синхронно(Если результат нужен немедленно).**
   В резольвере(*resolve*) просто делается запрос к **App 3**, а результат просто мержится и отдаётся **App 1**. Главное следить за таймаутами. Если таймауты не позволяют см. п.2.
2. **Асинхронно(Если результат нужен не сразу)**. Тут на помощь приходят подписки(*subscriptions*). При запросе **App 1** -> **App 2** присходит подписка и создаётся джоб(job) который сделает запрос **App 2** ->  **App 3**, смержит и вернёт результат подписчику(**App 1**).